# Print command from C# application

Tags: command-line, crystal-reports, dos

I want to write code that will print the Crystal Reports. But this command must go through DOS commands. How it is possible. (this is our client requirement)

Comment: you can invoke programs with command lines arguments with process/processstartinfo

Comment: What do the commands look like? If you were do execute these commands in a command prompt, what would it look like?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you need to create the DOS commands that will print the reports? If so, then create a reporting library and a console app and parse the command line arguments to perform the appropriate action. Using a reporting library will allow you to use the logic in other applications and in a console application.